# Losing Authentication after reload

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I am losing my manually set authentication after reloading the page in browser.
When I am loading the controller from the codesnippet below the first time, the variables `test_if_session_is_there` and `test_if_auth_is_there` are of course null.

But after reloading the controller (F5 in Browser) the variable `test_if_session_is_there` takes the value "Session is there" like it should, but `test_if_auth_is_there` stays null.

If I am doing `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` right after setting it (before reloading), I get the desired authentication, but after reloading, it is gone.

Can somebody tell me, why this is the case?

```
@Controller
public class MyAuthQuestionController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void entry(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session) {
        String test_if_session_is_there = (String) session.getAttribute("Test");
        Authentication test_if_auth_is_there = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        session.setAttribute("Test", "Session is there");
        UserDetailsAdapter userDetailsAdapter = new UserDetailsAdapter(new UserAccount());
        Authentication newAuth = new 
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetailsAdapter,"", userDetailsAdapter.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a vague theory: Your authentication result is request-scoped. You need to re-set it for every request as the new request (after reload) has no access to a previously requested authentication. That is the thing with auth-token (session-token) they are re-send and re-evaluated by the server for every request not just the first time.

Comment: @pandaadb Thank you for the comment. But Spring-Security should manage this part, should'nt it? How would I do it manually? Later on I would like to use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to configure HttpSecurity, so I can't really do it without the SecurityContext.